# Python script suddenly getting 'Terminated' with no other messages

Tags: ubuntu, python

Running Ubuntu 14, I have a script which runs in a tmux session 24/7. Sometimes when I come check on it, it will just have ended and say in the last line 'Terminated'. This happens arbitrarily, sometimes after 15 minutes and sometimes after 3 weeks.

Prior to this, I would occasionally get 'Killed' which I thought was due to oom issues. I decreased the memory usage and and now no longer get this message, but 'Terminated' instead.

What is the reason for this? And is there any syslog I can check to verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a limitation of OpenVZ - kernel logs are not available in instances. Also, my host was overselling resources which would kill my script when resource usage got too high.

Comment: How did you determine it was a system limitation?

Comment: An OpenVZ limitation? I'd been trying to use dmesg to get kernel logs so I deployed the app on a similar spec dedicated box. It too was terminated but this time dmesg showed it was killed for out of memory reasons.